# Access QVector element index by its content

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qvector

I have a `QVector` of `QStrings` and I want to remove element with its content, but I don't know how to find index of it.  Do you know how can I remove it? I don't want to iterate over it and compare its content by my value.

My `QVector` is declared as follows:

```
QVector <QString> user_valid;
```

and I want to remove it by its content, for example element with value "marigold":

```
user_valid.remove(user_valid.find("marigold");
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I would do the following if I were you:

- Use `QStringList` instead of `QVector<QString>` as it has convenience methods that can be useful for you; it is also more common and hence comprehensive. You would spare one extra method call even in this case.
- Just use the [removeOne()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html#removeOne) and/or [removeAll()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html#removeAll) methods depending on your exact scenario.

Therefore, I would be writing something like this:

```
QStringList user_valid;
user_valid << "marigold" << "cloud" << "sun" << "rain";
user_valid.removeOne("marigold");
// user_valid: ["cloud", ,"sun", "rain"]
```

If you really insist on using `QVector<QString>` - which is a bad idea in my opinion -, you would need to get the index first by the [indexOf()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvector.html#indexOf) method, so you would be writing this:

```
user_valid.remove(user_valid.indexOf("marigold"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_valid.remove(user_valid.indexOf("marigold"));
```